# useSWR with data specific to an authenticated user

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I want to use SWR to fetch data for the logged in user but I am not sure how to do this in the correct way.

e.g. say i want to get data from the api path `api/get/cards` for the particular user who is logged in. I could use `api/get/cards` for they key in SWR but then I assume the cache won't know that the data is specific to the current user only? And then the cache will just provide the data for the last user to user it and not necessarily the user who is currently calling it? What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about the endpoint api/get/cards? For example, do you have to pass in a unique identifier such as a user ID in the request as a query parameter?

Comment: I have to pass a unique identifier in the Authorisation header that identifies to the backend which user id it is and validates them.  So maybe i could use this unique identifier in the key i give to SWR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an array as the `key` parameter to `useSWR` for this precise scenario.

```js
const { data } = useSWR(['/api/get/cards', userId], (url, userId) => { /* Fetching logic */ })
```

The key of the request will now be the combination of both values, and will revalidate if the `userId` changes.