# Where is the cache that SWR maintains, client or server-side?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I am working on a Next JS project that uses SWR and was wondering where SWR's cache gets stored, is it on the client or in the server?

I am asking because if its on the client and so the cache is different for each user then i can make user-specific requests without worrying that the cache will show a user some other user's data

Comment: short answer client, long answer could be a mix depending on cache life time set on server, but nevertheless the heavy lifting is on client.

Comment: If i use the same key for an SWR call for the data of 2 different logged in users, can i be guaranteed that the cached data they will receive back will be the data specific to them? I assume If it's a client side cache then this will be true?

Comment: Yes, you can if you are using 2 different browsers.
You can't if you use one browser, for example, you get account information for account1 and it is cached, then you sign out and sign in with account2, you may get information for account1.

Comment: is there a way of clearing the SWR cache programmatically e.g. when a user signs out?

Comment: You can pass a user's specific id to SWR key to ensure the request revalidates if the user changes, as described in [useSWR with data specific to an authenticated user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68290605/1870780)

Comment: Is there a way to see the cache in Chrome Dev Tools?

Answer (score 3):

From the docs [cache](https://swr.vercel.app/advanced/cache):

> By default, SWR uses a global cache to store and share data across all components. Now, there's a new way to customize it with your own cache provider.

SWR use [Map](https://github.com/vercel/swr/blob/c677d042c1/src/utils/config.ts#L62) data type as the default cache provider

You can create your cache provider using JavaScript `Map` data type like `const provider = new Map()`.

Theoretically, you can use any data type, state management library like `redux`, web storage, `cookies`, IndexDB as your cache provider.

The cache provider must match the following definition:

```
interface Cache<Data = any> {
  get(key: string): Data | null | undefined
  set(key: string, value: Data): void
  delete(key: string): void
}
```

In performance considerations, client-side memory cache, web storage is very fast to read and write, so it is better to use client-side cache.

Server-side caching generally uses distributed caching technologies such as Redis.

Comment: what does "global" mean in this instance? is each cache specific to a client?

Comment: @user3472360 A single instance object throughout the life of the application that is only created when the application is initialized and destroyed when the application exits