# How to fetch data when state changes in React using useSWR?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swr

I have a use case where you can select users from a select menu, and when you do the app will display the data of the selected user.

When the page loads I get the data of the first user in the array `allUsers?.[0]`:

```js
const [userSelected, setUserSelected] = useState(allUsers?.[0])
```

The issue I'm having is, when I select another user from the select menu, the data does not get fetched.

I'm using [useSWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) to fetch the data and below is my ManageUsers component where I defined useSWR and the fetchers:

```js
export default function ManageUsers() {
  const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())

  const { data: allUsers, error: allUsersError } = useSWR(
    "/api/getUsers",
    fetcher
  )

  const [userSelected, setUserSelected] = useState(allUsers?.[0])

  const fetchUserByUserId = async (url) =>
    await fetch(url, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        userId: userSelected?.userId,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }).then((res) => res.json())

  const { data: userById, error: userByIdError } = useSWR(
    "/api/getUserByUserId",
    fetchUserByUserId
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userSelected) {
      fetchHoursByUserId(
        `/api/getUserByUserId?userId=${userSelected.userId}`
      )
    }
  }, [userSelected])

return (<>...</>)
}
```

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should include `userSelected?.userId` in the key of the `useSWR` call that fecthes individual user's data, e.g. `useSWR(["/api/getUserByUserId", userSelected?.userId], fetchUserByUserId)`. See [useSWR with data specific to an authenticated user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68276600/useswr-with-data-specific-to-an-authenticated-user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error may be occurring, because your fetcher functions are being redefined when a user is selected, since your `userSelected` state changes. I believe this messes up `useSWR` auto fetching because you call a different function every time after the component mounts, and `useSWR` may be unable to map these with it's cached data. It appears this is how it [natively works](https://github.com/vercel/swr/discussions/600).

In `useSWR's` own example [documentation](https://swr.vercel.app/examples/error-handling), the fetcher function is always defined outside the scope of the component to prevent this.

Try re-factoring your code, so that your fetcher functions are pure functions, where every variable they need can be provided in the parameters, and they can be defined outside the functional component. For example `fetchUsersById` can be defined like so:

```
  const fetchUserByUserId = async (url, userSelected) =>
    await fetch(url, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        userId: userSelected?.userId,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }).then((res) => res.json())
```

And then define them outside the scope of the component. That way, when you call them, its always the same instance of the function being called.

You can then take a look at this [documentation](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments) to supply your fetcher function multiple arguments.

Let me know if this resolves the issue.

Note I also noticed the following:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (userSelected) {
      fetchHoursByHairdresserId(
        `/api/getUserByUserId?userId=${userSelected.userId}`
      )
    }
  }, [userSelected])
```

Here you call `fetchHoursByHairdresserId`, but I don't see this function defined. If this is a typo, this also might be the source of your woes.

Comment: So useSWR should be used in a parent component and its data passed via props to presentational components?

I have a case where I fetch data via useSWR, make a DELETE request. The UI take a bit to update (useSWR to detect changes). I was thinking of using it in conjuction with useState.